# How to test for success after calling a AngularJS factory service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wondering how I could check wether or not a function was successfull or had an error. I check for this in the function itself. but how can I recheck the result when calling the service.

I've tried something like this

```
      entryService.update($scope.entry)
        .success(function(){
          $scope.entry = data;
          $state.go('entry', {id: $scope.entry._id});
        }).error(function(){
          error = true;
        });
```

This however doesn't work. And I was wondering how to get a similar result?

My service funtion looks like this:

```
angular.module('academiaUnitateApp')
    .factory('entryService',function($http){
        var service = {};

        service.update = function(entry, callback){
            $http.put('/api/entrys/' + entry._id, entry)
                .success(callback, function(data){
                    console.log('Updated entry : ', data);
                })
                .error(callback, function(error){
                    console.log("Couldn't update entry. Error : ", error);
                });
        };

        return service;
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can return true or false from the function for success or failure.

Answer (score 1):

Check comments on code

```
 entryService.update($scope.entry)
    .success(function(){
      $scope.entry = data;
      $state.go('entry', {id: $scope.entry._id});
    }).error(function(){
      error = true;
    });


angular.module('academiaUnitateApp')
.factory('entryService',function($http){
    var service = {};

    service.update = function(entry, callback){
        $http.put('/api/entrys/' + entry._id, entry)
            .success(callback, function(data){
                console.log('Updated entry : ', data);
            })
            .error(callback, function(error){
                console.log("Couldn't update entry. Error : ", error);
                //IF ERROR, RETURN NULL
                return null;
            });
     //MUST RETURN DATA HERE TO ALLOW .SUCCESS TO RUN
     return data;
    };

    return service;
 });
```

The return data in Update function, will make the success ( or .done) function to be called.

Comment: Had to take back the "accept" mark, sorry. 
The reason is that I after trying your solution is having an error saying that `undefined is not a function` on my `.success` in my `entryService.update`